# Bad Request, Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: request

There are two application servers and a switch. When i access application by using application server ip it works fine. However if i use switch ip in my url Bad request error throws up only for firefox and chrome for a few links only.

Comment: What kind of "switch" do you use? It might be your load balancer tampers with the request data and forwards it in a way your app server does not understand. Illegal UTF-8 or truncated headers are likely candidates...

Comment: Maybe you are using some special characters that causes this error.

Comment: @Sasivarnakumar i also had the same problem and your notice helped me then i can answer... thank you . i just remove the space and tabs in my header

Comment: We had this on a Windows Server with IIS where the SAML request sent to the server was too large, because some users were members of more than 300 Windows groups. These were all sent in the SAML request which resulted in a too large request size.

Answer (score 61):

[Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21384722) is a detailed explanation & solution for this problem from ibm.

**Problem(Abstract)**

Request to HTTP Server fails with Response code 400.

**Symptom**

Response from the browser could be shown like this:

Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.

HTTP Server Error.log shows the following message:
"request failed: error reading the headers"

**Cause**

This is normally caused by having a very large Cookie, so a request header field exceeded the limit set for Web Server.

**Diagnosing the problem**

To assist with diagnose of the problem you can add the following to the LogFormat directive in the httpd.conf:
error-note: %{error-notes}n

**Resolving the problem**

For server side:
Increase the value for the directive LimitRequestFieldSize in the httpd.conf:
LimitRequestFieldSize 12288 or 16384
For How to set the LimitRequestFieldSize, check [Increase the value of LimitRequestFieldSize in Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/413984/increase-the-value-of-limitrequestfieldsize-in-apache)

For client side:
Clear the cache of your web browser should be fine.

Comment: how to find the `httpd.conf`. I am using ubuntu and apache tomcat7.0.34

Comment: *"This is normally caused by having a very large Cookie, so a request header field exceeded the limit set for Web Server."* - Right and then in turn, possibly having a corrupted cookie on the client side, which is what happened to me today. One has to go in to the privacy settings and delete the offending cookie(s).

Comment: I am getting the same issue while using AWS ELB. "One has to go into the privacy settings and delete the offending cookie(s)." I tried this still no use

Comment: @amitbhardwaj you can find the httpd.conf by using this command
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Answer (score 31):

If you use Apache httpd web server in version above 2.2.15-60, then it could be also because of underscore `_` in hostname.

https://ma.ttias.be/apache-httpd-2-2-15-60-underscores-hostnames-now-blocked/

Comment: Jeez.... many thanks! hours wasted. why doesn't apache2ctl configtest detect this?

Answer (score 11):

I just deleted my stored cookies, site data, and cache from my browser...
It worked. I'm using firefox...

Answer (score 10):

THIS IS CAUSED BY TOO MANY COOKIES!

To SOLVE - Chrome:  go into 'developer mode' -> ctrl + shift + i

On top you will see console, network and LITTLE BUTTON THAT LOOKS LIKE ARROWS  >>>   click on that for APPLICATION

On Left, under STORAGE, find COOKIES.

There will be little DOWN ARROW indicating a drop down, click on this.

now you will see the website something like:  [www.investing.com](http://www.investing.com)

RIGHT CLICK IT and select Clear

Reload.

Works!

---

Alternatively, clear cookies and cache in a traditional way, and it will work too.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you url encode all of the query params in your url.

In my case there was a space ' ' in my url, and I was making an API call using curl, and my api server was giving this error.

Means the following url
`http://somedomain.com?key=some value with space`

should be 
`http://somedomain.com/?key=some%20value%20with%20space`

Answer (score 4):

In my case is a **cookie-related** issue, I had many cookies with extremely big values, and that was causing the problem.

You can replicate this issue here on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com), just open the console and type this:

```js
[ ...Array(5) ].forEach((i, idx) => {
    document.cookie = `stackoverflow_cookie${idx}=${'a'.repeat(4000)}`;
});
```

What is that?

I am creating 5 cookies with a string of length or value of 4000 bytes; then reload the page and you will see the same issue.

I tried it on [google.com](https://google.com) and you'll get the error but they automatically clear the cookies for you, which is a nice fallback to start fresh.

Answer (score 3):

I was testing my application with special characters & was observing the same error. After some research, turns out the **%** symbol was the cause. I had to modify it to the encoded representation **%25**. Its all fine now, thanks to the below post

https://superuser.com/questions/759959/why-does-the-percent-sign-in-a-url-cause-an-http-400-bad-request-error

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party, but bumped in to this issue whilst working with the openidc auth module.

I ended up noticing that cookies were not being cleared properly, and I had at least 10 mod_auth_openidc_state_... cookies, all of which would be sent by my browser whenever I made a request.

If this sounds familiar to you, double check your cookies!

Comment: I am using Sanctum with Laravel and had placed the 'sanctum' middleware on my web routes instead of 'auth'. The cookies piled up and eventually the request header was too large. Changing the web middleware to auth and deleting the cookies fixed it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

in my case:

in header

> Content-Type<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>

or

> Content-Type<kbd>tab</kbd>

with two space or tab

when i remove it then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

in my magento2 website ,show exactly the same error when click a product,

my solution is to go to edit the value of Search Engine Optimization - URL Key of this product,

make sure that there are only alphabet,number and - in URL Key,
such as 100-washed-cotton-duvet-cover-set,
deleting all other special characters ,such as % .

Answer (score 0):

I got `Bad Request, Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand`
when I tried to download a file to the target machine using `curl`.
I solved it by instead using `scp` to copy the file from the source machine to the
target machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error on the WordPress website, check the below solution.

1. Corrupted Browser Cache & Cookies: Delete your Cookies and clear your cache
2. Restart your server

Answer (score 0):

For GET Request make sure that passing parameters are url encoded.
if you are using php you can use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function

Answer (score 0):

If you have this same problem and none of the other solutions worked, please check again the url.

In my case it was a space in the end, when it was added to the Cronjob, someone also copied a blank space by accident.

Answer (score 0):

check your data types are correct or not.

for ex: if you send the file, you need to consider to send the full object of the file

Answer (score 0):

when I use curl to post a request, I see this error.
The root cause is `-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`,  **but body is empty**.   When I add `-d ''`,   the response is success.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle fusion, when running rest call for cancelling ess job requests you get the ERROR CODE 411 :
Bad Request, Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

To resolve this add the header key "Content-Length" with value "0" (without cotes) in addition to the key "Content-Type" with value "application/json". Postman add the Content-Length key by default.