# Hide URL parameter on Wordpress using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, parameters

I have this website on WordPress that has a page for every user.

The link is, for example, http://mywordpress.com.br/. But every user has his own page, which is http://mywordpress.com.br/user/?id=username.

I need to make this page looks like http://mywordpress.com.br/username , but the thing is, when someone types http://mywordpress.com.br/username on the browser it needs to redirect to http://mywordpress.com.br/user/?id=username, but it has to show http://mywordpress.com.br/username.

I've read many threads about this but I still couldn't figure it out, I know I have to change .htaccess and I`ve tried on many different ways, none of them worked.

Does anybody knows how to do that?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [P] flag of the rewrite engine so that your request get proxied to the another url. This will work without changing the browser url. You request a resource through a url which will get proxied to your new url without the user getting a chance to know that this is proxied.

The code for the same is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mywordpress.com.br/user/?id=$1 [NE,P,L]
```

Working example is at [.htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=4df08fc9-0ba3-5fe2-9f55-4c193573b6d8)

I would like to give a suggestion to have the url of the form http://mywordpress.com.br/user/username rather than http://mywordpress.com.br/username because writing a rewrite rule at base level will catch all other urls too like http://mywordpress.com.br/blog-post-title.

You can modify then the rewrite rule as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /user
RewriteRule ^user/(.*) http://mywordpress.com.br/user/?id=$1 [NE,P,L]
```

Working example is at [.htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=33a9e62e-0b1c-5d98-89cd-95d5bcfef96e)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, the problem now is, when I try one of those urls ( ex: /user/admin) I get this error:
`Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
` 

Do you know why this is happening? Can`t fix it..

Comment: This is a separate issue.It is probably an issue with cookies.Try clearing the cookies. For more detailed answer you can visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309751/bad-request-your-browser-sent-a-request-that-this-server-could-not-understand . The rewrite rule solves the question that you mentioned so do upvote and accept the answer so that other SO users can benefit from the same.