# Is there any replacement of <textarea> in html when it holds many records and returns the "Bad Request" error?

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle

I am trying to use the hidden  as a text board to keep and print-out based on the SQL query returns in a PHP form. However, it seems like it has the limitation or size issues when the query returns a great number of records (When it returns several records it goes fine) when I clicked on the search button, the error is as below :
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
Referer
/n

Is there any other similar function in HTML that I can use as a text board instead of  or is there any way that I can use to resize the ? My script is as below, and I very much appreciate the help!

```
<?php 


$db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = **.**.**.**)(PORT = ****)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)))";


if(isset($_GET["status"]) )
{  

$region1 = $_GET['region'];
$year1 = $_GET['year'];
$status1 = $_GET['status'];


$objConnect = ocilogon("******","*****",$db);
//$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM SR4 WHERE STATUS = '$status1' by FIELDBOOK";  
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM SR4 WHERE AREA LIKE '$region1' and YEAR = '$year1' and STATUS LIKE '$status1' order by FIELDBOOK";  
$objParse = oci_parse ($objConnect, $strSQL);  
oci_execute ($objParse, OCI_DEFAULT);  

?>


<table bgcolor ="white" class="grid-view" cellspacing="7" cellpadding="10" rules="rows" border="2" align = "center" width="1000" border="3" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1" style="color:#333333;">  

<tr style="color:White;background-color:#3A3F45;font-weight:bold;"    >  
<th width="70"> <div align="center">SR #</div></th>
<th width="30"> <div align="center">EA </div></th>  
<th width="30"> <div align="center">DEPT </div></th>  
<th width="30"> <div align="center">CITY </div></th>  
<th width="70"> <div align="center">CORTE </div></th>  
<th width="30"> <div align="center">PMB </div></th>  
<th width="30"> <div align="center">PME </div></th>
<th width="30"> <div align="center">TYPE </div></th>
<th width="30"> <div align="center">AREA </div></th>
<th width="180"> <div align="center">CHIEF </div></th>
<th width="30"> <div align="center">STATUS </div></th>
<th width="30"> <div align="center">FOLDER PATH</div></th> 
</tr>  

<?php


while(($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false) 
{  
    $gotSomeRows = true;
    $fieldbook = $objResult["FIELDBOOK"];
    $project = $objResult["PROJECT"];
    $dept = $objResult["DEPT"];
    $community = $objResult["COMMUNITY"];
    $corte = $objResult["CORTE"];
    $pmb = $objResult["PMB"];
    $pme = $objResult["PME"];
    $type = $objResult["TYPE"];
    $area = $objResult["AREA"];
    $officesupervisor = $objResult["OFFICESUPERVISOR"];
    $status = $objResult["STATUS"];
    $user_arr[] = array($fieldbook,$project,$dept,$community,$corte,$pmb,$pme,$type,$area,$officesupervisor,$status);



?>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=&#39;#C0C0C0&#39;;this.style.cursor=&#39;pointer&#39;;" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=&#39;#FFFFFF&#39;;">

<td><div align="center"><a href="http://sv07gisdev1/query/sr.php?CusID=<?=$objResult["FIELDBOOK"];?>"><font size="2.95"><b><?php echo $fieldbook;?></b></font></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $project; ?></td>  
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $dept; ?></td>  
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $community; ?></div></td>  
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $corte; ?></div></td> 
<td align="center"><?php echo $pmb; ?></td>  
<td align="center"><?php echo $pme; ?></td> 
<td align="center"><?php echo $type; ?></td> 
<td align="center"><?php echo $area; ?></td> 
<td align="center"><?php echo $officesupervisor; ?></td> 
<td align="center"><?php echo $status; ?></td> 
<td align="center"><A HREF=http://10.56.12.59/surveys/notes/<?=$objResult["YEAR"];?>/<?=$objResult["FIELDBOOK"];?>><font size="2.8">View Folder</font></A></td> 

</tr>

<?php
}
if (!isset($gotSomeRows)){

    echo "<p align='center'><b> <font face=verdana color=Grey  size='4pt'>No Reocrd Found</font></b> </p>";
    $user_arr[] = '';
}

?>  

<?php  

$serailze_user_arr = serialize($user_arr);


}

?>  

</table>  


<textarea name='export_data' id="InputTextArea" placeholder="placeholder"><?php echo $serailze_user_arr;?></textarea>
```

Comment: This is a server error so has nothing to do with the HTML. It sounds like you have a hidden input with a large amount of text in it, that's too much for your server to handle. That's going to be dependent on your web server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when I echo/print the array it has not issue even thought it a large amount of the text.

Comment: This is happening when you submit whatever is on your page back to the server, so has nothing to do with php. Also, you may want to check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309751/bad-request-your-browser-sent-a-request-that-this-server-could-not-understand