# (Error:400 Bad Request) in codeigniter after resubmitting the form

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I am working on a project where all the data is stored as cookies instead of sessions and it is working well but I have some pages where I used the form to post data to the server and whenever I post the multipart form i.e.,
for eg.,

```
<? 
   $attr = array('name' => 'form_name', 'id' => 'form_name');
   echo form_open_multipart('form_submit', $attr); 
   some html inputs...
   echo form_close();
?>
```

The form is getting submitted through controller and after successfully submitted and performed operations I am redirecting to the previous page itself some successful responses but when I reload the page using F5 I am getting a 400 Bad Request error stating **"Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."** and **"Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.11 Server at localhost Port 80"**. Can you help me out?

I already went through **[Bad Request, Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309751/bad-request-your-browser-sent-a-request-that-this-server-could-not-understand)** but couldn't get the solution. Hoping for help!

Comment: please add some more details: are you using ajax to submit the form, if not, where is the form action coming from? from a controller `form_submit` and its method `index()` ?

Comment: @Vickel sorry, i am submitting normally using jquery submit() function which is  after form validations and the page is posted to controller's method form_submit() and first time if i submit the form, it is getting submitted and all the operations are working fine but the problem is when i reload or refresh the page after form submitted the form has to get resubmitted but its showing the error which i mentioned above.